# RedisToGo - remote Redis server. When to use one?

Tags: performance, storage, remote, nosql, redis

I like the concept of relying on third-party service hosting my data but what's the point of using super-fast NoSQL storage via remote hosting?

It maybe in different datacenter or even country! And network calls always cost a lot in comparison with local storage.

Or should I use a service like this just in case when I don't query it very often?

Answer (score 3):

> what's the point of using super-fast
>   NoSQL storage via remote hosting?

Because your web/application server is presumably at the remote site as well, thereby enabling it to query the NoSQL database at LAN speeds and then deliver the resulting webpage to your users.

Answer (score 1):

Hosted Redis is a double edged sword. While you don't have to install and maintain the server, your app's performance will be variable. You should pick hosted redis only when the ping times are very low. If you are not sure, ask for their IP and do a ping/tracert from your server (not from your laptop).

Answer (score 0):

Also presumably both your site and remote redis server are located in datacenters, so connection is fast.

Someone did the test and reported something like 8 000 - 10 000 ops per second if use machine in different data center. This is still huge performance.